# Designing widget with system theme colors

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm creating small widget and I'm getting pretty frustrated with it. Earlier I was just setting colors as I seen it and it was ok. But now I would like to make it to match system theme settings. How it can be achieved?

As I was requested to post some code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- pasek górny z przyciskiem dodawania -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="37dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/AddButton"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:contentDescription="Add" />
    </GridLayout>

    <!-- panel z wiadomościami -->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <!-- stopka widgetu -->
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/Footer"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want my widget to blend in system this time. As I can use themes which provide some icons, some colors and graphics I would my widget to use those colors to match other components. Is it possible?

Comment: Post some code to share the points you are confused about. Also, what do you mean by matching theme settings?

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't set any `android:color`, `android:background` or such, the views will inherit colours from your theme.

So first make sure you are inheriting from a theme that satisfies you.

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.Material">

</style>
```

- About your widgets, if their natural tint is not what your looking for, then you have to customize the above mentioned theme from styles.xml. You can easily find how to style buttons, listviews and such.

Here is an example for buttons:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="Theme.Material">
<item name="android:ButtonStyle">@style/MyStyle.Buttons</item>
...
</style>

<style name="MyStyle.Buttons" parent="Widget.Material.Button">
<item name="android:background">@color/my_color</item>
...
</style>
```

First you say that all buttons should be styled from `MyStyle.Buttons`. Then you define `MyStyle.Buttons` and add all the features you want. This way **all your buttons** will have the same background, and you **don't** need to do it by hand.

There's plenty of questions about this topic.

Comment: Well so I just overestimated this. So the only way is to extend one of android themes and set all colors inside. And those colors I need to define in my style. So the only way to make my App Widget blendin with system widgets is to make it so all by hand, and it will work with only one branded ROM.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, see my edited answer. Defining styles is the easiest way to color your widgets, and the attributes you set in styles.xml propagate to all the widgets you create. You don't have to do it by hand for, say, each single button. This has nothing to do with ROMs.

Comment: I do  understand. What you posted is helpful but not exactly what I am looking for. I was just looking for way to read background color or some other colors from system to make my widget look similar to other ones installed. You answer I can not read those, but I can easily set any color as background to use in whole app easily, but first it has to be set in my styles.xml file by exact value.